# python Global Interpreter Lock GIL problem

Tags: python, gil

I want to provide a service on the web that people can test out the performance of an algo, which is written in python and running on the linux machine

basically what I want to do is that, there is a very trivial PHP handler, let's say start_algo.php, which accepts the request coming from browser, and in the php code through system() or popen() (something like exec( "python algo.py" ) ) to issue a new process running the python script, I think it is doable in this part

problem is that since it is a web service, surely it has to serve multiple users at the same time, but I am quite confused by the Global Interpreter Lock GIL http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock
that the 'standard' CPython has implemented,
does it mean, if I have 3 users running the algo now (which means 3 separated processes, correct me if I am wrong plz), at a particular moment, there is only one user is being served by the Python interpreter and the other 2 are waiting for their turns?

Many thanks in advance

Ted

Comment: Are you using Apache and `mod_wsgi`?  If so, concurrent requests are handled at that level well outside Python.  If not, please explain why you're not using Apache (or nginx) and mod_wsgi.

Comment: @S.Lott thx, but the problem is not about the concurrent REQUESTS, it is about concurrently running the python script cuz those script will take a long time to run whereas the php code will simply return after issuing the "python algo.py" cmd

Comment: The question conflates concurrent requests with each request running a script.  The question is confusing.  Any time you mention the GIL in the context of Apache and mod_wsgi, you have to explain what -- precisely -- you think is going on.  Apache separates the requests.  Each request forks a **separate** process.  Please be perfectly clear that you understand that each separate request (made separate by Apache and mod_wsgi) actually submits a separate subprocess.  Please be very clear -- in the question -- that you understand this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are opening each script by invoking a new process; you will not run afoul of the GIL.  Each process gets its own interpreter and therefore its own interpreter lock.

Comment: thx a lot, very speedy and helpful, per-process-per-GIL basis makes sense to me

Answer (score 7):

[The GIL is per-process.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585181/is-the-python-gil-really-per-interpreter) If you start multiple `python` processes, each will have its own GIL that prevents the interpreter(s) in this specific process from running more than one thread at a time. But independent processes can run at the same time.

Also, multiple threads inside one Python process do take turns on running (rather frequently, IIRC once per hundred opcode instructions or a few dozen milliseconds depending on the version), so it's not like the GIL prevents concurrency at all - it just prevents *multi*-threading.

Comment: thank you a lot delnan, very detailed explanation, I should do more homework before asking, similar question has been asked on this site already