# python ThreadPool not working (executed sequentially instead of in parallel)

Tags: python-2.7, threadpool, python-multiprocessing

I'm using `ThreadPool` from `multiprocessing.pool` but it seems it is not working (i.e. it is executed sequentially rather than in parallel: `res1` takes 14s, `res2` takes 11s, and using `ThreadPool` takes 27s instead of 14s).

I think the problem is in `another_method` because it uses a (shared) `read_only_resource`.

I've tried having a `time.sleep(val)` in `another_method` instead of calling another method (works as expected - it takes as long as the maximum value I pass) and I've also tried to pass a deep copy of the `read_only_resource` (this doesn't work, it takes 27s).

I have run out of things to try to make this work:

```
def method(text_type, read_only_resource):
  value = some_processesing(text_type)
  return another_method(value, read_only_resource)


def main(): 
  same_read_only_resource = get_read_only_resource()
  pool = ThreadPool(processes=2)
  res1 = pool.apply_async(method, (some_text_type, same_read_only_resource))
  res2 = pool.apply_async(method, (other_text_type, same_read_only_resource))

  results1 = res1.get()
  results2 = res2.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use `map` instead of `apply_async`. The `apply_async` function isn't for parallelizing multiple function calls. Rather, it's to asynchronously call a single instance of the function. Since you call it twice and get the results in order, you get serialized performance.

Calling `map` will run multiple instances of a function in parallel. It requires packing the inputs into a single object, e.g. a tuple, since it only allows a single argument to be passed to your function. Then all packed inputs can be placed in a list or other iterable and given to `map`, for example:

```
work_args =[(some_text, read_only_resource), (other_text, read_only_resource), ... ]
results = pool.map(method, work_args)
```

Additionally you can use something like `itertools.izip()` to create `work_args`, e.g.:

```
work_args = itertools.izip([some_text, other_text, ...], read_only_resource)
```

Note that since you are using `ThreadPool`, you still might not get much performance increase, depending on the work being done. The topic has been discussed in many places, but Python may not parallelize with *threads* like you expect, due to the Global Interpreter Lock. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7405026/4765406) for a good summary. In short, if your function is going to do I/O, `ThreadPool` can help.

However if you use `multiprocessing.Pool`, you will have multiple processes executing simultaneously. Just replace `ThreadPool` with `Pool` to use it.